# Clustering histograms of different lengths in Python

Tags: python, numpy

How can I cluster a large dataset of histograms with the same # of bins (8), but of different lengths? Specifically, I'd like to cluster their density distributions. I think I can do this with kmeans or hierarchical clustering, but it seems that the lengths are an issue or my setup is causing `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

```
hist_data[:, 1]
array([
   array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6,
   6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
   6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
   6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
   6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
   6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
   6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
   6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
   5], dtype=int64),
   ...,
   array([6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
   3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
   6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
   3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
   6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
   6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
   5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
   5, 5], dtype=int64)], dtype=object)
```

Comment: make bin count vector of length 8 and cluster

Comment: @NathanMcCoy do you mean a bin count vector for each histogram? or a single vector with a total count

Comment: take max histo length and consider others filled with 0 on those places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this fit the bill:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

data = hist_data[:, 1]
data = np.array([np.bincount(datum, minlength=9) for datum in data])
km = KMeans(n_clusters = 10, init="k-means++").fit(data)  # 10 clusters
print(km.cluster_centers_)  # cluster centres, 10x8 array
```

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'`. From `data = np.array([np.bincount(datum) for datum in data])`

Comment: look like one of your histogram has dtype('0') rather than 'int64'. Check it via `np.unique([str(datum.dtype) for datum in hist_data[:,1])`

Comment: actually, that errors may indicate that your histograms do not have same bin count. Check it via `np.unique([len(np.bincount(datum)) for datum in hist_data[:,1]])`. If they have the same bin count the above command should output 8.

Comment: `np.unique([len(np.bincount(datum)) for datum in hist_data[:,1]])` gives me the same TypeError as before

Comment: `np.unique([str(datum.dtype) for datum in hist_data[:,1]])`
 returns `array(['int64', 'object'], dtype='<U6')`

Comment: There is at least one histogram which is not an array in your data. Find its id via `[i for i in range(len(hist_data[:,1])) if str(hist_data[:,1][i].dtype) != 'int64']`. After that, you may want to remove those histograms or try to convert it to int64.
If your data is not so big you can upload it somewhere then I can have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194775/discussion-between-tu-bui-and-rafvasq).